# Run Python SimpleHTTPServer when raspberry Pi turns on

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How would you start SimpleHTTPServer when the Pi boots up?

I made a startup.sh with python -m SimpleHTTPServer & but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using @restart "your command" in your crontab?

Try `crontab -e`, and see add `@restart python -m SimpleHTTPServer`